# RxSwift BehaviorRelay cancel previous calls, only use the most recent

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a `BehaviorRelay` setup to store an array of addresses, and then I observe that `BehaviorRelay` so that I can create an `MKAnnotation` array and then display that on the map.

```
let addresses = BehaviorRelay<[Address]>(value: [])
```

I make network requests when the user moves the map to a new area.
If the user moves the map very quickly, I can end up with several network requests

I only want the latest response.

This is where my problem begins.

```
    addresses.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (value) in
        self.fetchAllAnnotationsAndAddToMap()
    }).disposed(by: disposebag)
```

`fetchAllAnnotationsAndAddToMap`gets called every time addresses is set.

`fetchAllAnnotationsAndAddToMap` can take a long time to complete. Requests to run `fetchAllAnnotationsAndAddToMap`get stacked up and all of them run to completion.

What I want to happen is once `addresses` is set again, I want for all former calls to be discarded and only use the latest.

I've heard this is what `flatMapLatest` is for.

However, flatMapLatest requires I return an observable and I'm confused by that.

How do I cancel the methods called after the `BehaviorRelay` is updated and only use the most recent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to break up your `fetchAllAnnotationsAndAddToMap()` function into two functions. Then you can:

```
addresses.asObservable()
    // you might want to put a `debounce` call in here.
    .flatMapLatest { addresses in 
        return fetchAllAnnotations(from: addresses)
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] annotations in 
        self?.addToMap(annotations)
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably using a `flatMapLatest` is a designated solution to this problem.However, I would like to propose another solution :

Simply re-initialize your `BehaviorRelay` again in your `subscribe` part of your code, and filter empty ones, Like this :

```
  addresses.asObservable().filter({$0.count >0}).subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (value) in
    self.fetchAllAnnotationsAndAddToMap()
    self.addresses = BehaviorRelay<[Address]>(value: [])
}).disposed(by: disposebag)
```

Comment: wouldn't this cancel all subscriptions to addresses?

Comment: @YichenBman Yes you are right, you should subscribe again, I have put the subscription code inside a UIbutton tap action. :(